# Why does second try in re.search errors out in second try and works in first try?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re, python-3.9

So, I was coding discord bot where I used on_message() to check if message contains banned word. However, it gave similar error during its execution so I tried to create a separate file to test the error. Here's the code that did similar work in discord bot.

```py
from re import search
from re import IGNORECASE
banned_words = (r"N[a-zA-Z0-9]gga")
for banned_word in banned_words:
    if search(banned_word, input("> "), IGNORECASE):
        print("N-word detected")
```

Here's the test

```py
root@kali:~# python3 test.py 
> nigga
N-word detected
> nigga
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/test.py", line 5, in <module>
    if search(banned_word, input("> "), IGNORECASE):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 201, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/re.py", line 304, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 948, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, state, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 443, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose, nested + 1,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/sre_parse.py", line 549, in _parse
    raise source.error("unterminated character set",
re.error: unterminated character set at position 0
```

What could go wrong here? Also it shouldn't loop more than once right? I wonder how it asked input() twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`banned_words` is the string `N[a-zA-Z0-9]gga`, so `for banned_word in banned_words:` iterates over the characters.

The first value of `banned_word` is the string `N`. The search for this succeeds.

The second value of `banned_word` is the string `[`. This is not a valid regexp by itself, it's the start of a `[...]` character set. So you get an error.

If `banned_words` is supposed to be a tuple, you need a comma:

```
banned_words = (r"N[a-zA-Z0-9]gga",)
```

But if you want to test multiple regular expressions you can simply put them all in a single regexp with `|` alternation:

```
banned_words = r"N[a-z0-9]gga|F[a-z0-9]+ck"
```

and then just do a single search rather than looping.

Comment: Oh, very awesome notice. I didn't realize it causes string to be formed instead of tuple without comma. I will accept this answer in 6 minutes

Answer (score 1):

I am not understanding what you are trying to do by looping `banned_words`. First time it was woking because in First iteration, `banned_word` is getting First character from `banned_words` which is N and that is in your typed word.

You can simply try this:

```
from re import search,IGNORECASE
banned_words = (r"N[a-zA-Z0-9]gga")

if search(banned_words, input("> "), IGNORECASE):
        print("N-word detected")
```

If you want input multiple time then try infinity `while` loop:

```
while True:
    if search(banned_words, input("> "), IGNORECASE):
        print("N-word detected")
```

**Note : This is infinity whole loop, and there are no condition to break loop! You can simply add break condition.**